# Vue component pass multiple objects as props not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to pass multiple props to a component via v-for --

```
<my-component v-for="(myobj, myid) in mydata"></my-component>
```

where mydata looks like --

```
mydata: {
  42: { txt: "Home", url: "https://google.com/" },
  43: { txt: "SO", url: "https://stackoverflow.com/" }
}
```

But couldn't get the simplest snippet to work --

https://codepen.io/jerryji/pen/yGOrbj?editors=1011

Any pointer will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `v-for` loop is not binding any data to the component. It's missing [`v-bind` directives](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind) for your bindings. It should look like this:

```
<my-component v-for="(myobj, myid) in mydata"
             :myobj="myobj"
             :myid="myid"></my-component>
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/QzNRpY?editors=1011)

Comment: You are my hero! Can't believe I missed something this basic.

Comment: @JerryJi No problem :)

Comment: Thanks Bro. This is great answer. I have applied it like this. `<my-component v-for="(item, index) in mydata" :source="data" :key="index" />`

Comment: @HoangTranSon No problem :)